# Proof of Complexity

Tags: proof-writing, computational-complexity

If I want to prove that $f=O(g)$ for $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ and $g(x)=x^{2/3}$, is it sufficient to say that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)/g(x)=0$?  I'm not sure if this is a convincing enough argument or more elaboration is required.

Comment: You can probably add that any convergent sequence is bounded (if that is how you have defined $O(\cdot)$)

Comment: It depends on the degree of rigor that’s expected. If you’re being held to a fairly high standard, you could simply prove the theorem that $f$ is $O(g)$ if $f(x)/g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, using the definitions of $O$ and limit. As @Prahlad indirectly pointed out, all you actually need is that $f(x)/g(x) is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is absolutely true -- always.  Why?

If $f(x)\rightarrow g(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$, then there is some constant $N>0$ such that $\lvert f(x)/g(x)\rvert\leq 1$ for all $x\geq N$. But this means that for all $x\geq N$, we have $\lvert f(x)\rvert\leq \lvert g(x)\rvert$; under the (usual) assumption that $g\geq 0$, this implies that for $x\geq N$ we have $\lvert f(x)\rvert\leq g(x)$, and hence $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Do you mean $| \frac{f}{g} |< \varepsilon, \varepsilon >0$ and arbitrarily small?

Comment: @Alex Well, you can certainly prove that... but there's not actually any reason to.  We are trying to prove that $f=O(g)$, not $f=o(g)$. So, $\lvert\frac{f}{g}\rvert$ eventually bounded is enough... and it is certainly eventually bounded by 1.

Comment: I understand. I was a bit baffled by your choice on 1 as the upper bound. Clearly any $\epsilon>0$ works because in this case $f=o(g)$